# How can I take out(or slice) the elements in a rank-2 tensor , whose first element is unique?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, unique

My title might be ambiguous due to my awkward English. But I mean this:
suppose i have a tensor `a` like this:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 2, 3],
       [2, 2, 4],
       [3, 2, 3],
       [4, 2, 3]], dtype=int32)
```

**the 'first column' of this tensor could contain duplicate elements (e.g.  [1, 2, 2, 3, 4] or [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5]), and which element is duplicated is not known beforehand.**

and i wanna take out a tensor this:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 2, 3],
       [3, 2, 3],
       [4, 2, 3]], dtype=int32)
```

as u can see, I take out the rows whose first element is a unique element in the column of `a`.

I first wanted to use the function `tf.unique()` . BUT the `idx` value returned by it doesn't indicate the first index of each value of output tensor in the original tensor.

`tf.unique()` works like this:

```
# tensor 'x' is [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7, 8, 8]
y, idx = tf.unique(x)
y ==> [1, 2, 3, 7, 8]
idx ==> [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

The function `tf.unique(x, name=None)` finds the unique elements in a 1-D tensor. And it now returns two value: `y` and `idx`. `y` contains all of the unique elements of `x` sorted inthe same order that they occur in `x`. `idx` contains the index of each value of `x` in the unique output `y`.

How I wish it has a third return value which contains the first index of each value of `y` in the original tensor `x` is also needed. It might work like this:

```
# tensor 'x' is [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7, 8, 8]
y, idx, idx_ori  = tf.unique(x)
y ==> [1, 2, 3, 7, 8]
idx ==> [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
idx_ori ==> [0, 2, 3, 6, 7]
```

Just like its equivalent in Numpy does:

```
array 'x' is [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7, 8, 8]
y, idx_ori = np.unique(x, return_index=True)
y ==> [1, 2, 3, 7, 8]
idx_ori ==> [0, 2, 3, 6, 7]
```

IF i have this `idx_ori`, i can solve my problem by `tf.gather()`:

```
_, _1, idx_ori = tf.unique(a[:, 0])
result = tf.gather(a, idx_ori)
```

Any idea to workaround this problem?   or any idea to get this indices that i want.

P.S. I know my description is tediously long ... :-p

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit gross, but you could do:

```
print a
y, idx = tf.unique(a[:,0])
z = tf.one_hot(idx, tf.shape(y)[0])
s = tf.cumsum(z)
e = tf.equal(s, 1)  # only seen once so far
ss = tf.to_int32(e) * tf.to_int32(z) # and we equal the thing
m = tf.reduce_max(ss, reduction_indices=1)
out = tf.boolean_mask(a, tf.equal(m, 1))
sess = tf.Session()
print sess.run(out)

[[1 2 3]
 [2 2 3]
 [2 2 4]
 [3 2 3]
 [4 2 3]]
[[1 2 3]
 [2 2 3]
 [3 2 3]
 [4 2 3]]
```